# Trouble with installation of gstreamer gem in Linux Mint

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, rvm

I'm using linux mint. When I try to install with `gem install gstreamer` I see this error:

```
    ERROR:  Error installing gstreamer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb`
    checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wextra option to compiler... yes

    checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes

    checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes

    checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... yes

    checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes

    checking for -Wswitch-default option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wswitch-enum option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes

    checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes
    checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes
    checking for rb_define_alloc_func() in ruby.h... yes
    checking for rb_block_proc() in ruby.h... yes

    checking for new allocation framework... yes
    checking for attribute assignment... no
    checking for Win32 OS... no
    checking for gstreamer-1.0... no

    checking for sudo... yes
    installing 'libgstreamer1.0-dev' native package... failed
    failed to run '/usr/bin/sudo -p \[sudo\]\ password\ for\ \%u\     to\ install\ \<libgstreamer1.0-dev\>:\  apt-get install -V -y libgstreamer1.0-dev'
```

.
        *** extconf.rb failed ***
        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

```
 Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
--with-override-variables
--without-override-variables

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/gstreamer-2.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/gstreamer-2.2.0/gem_make.out
```

Here's my ruby version:

`ruby 2.1.2p95`

And my rubygems version

`2.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what helped me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0
```