# Trouble with playing videos in green_shoes gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gstreamer, shoes, linux-mint

Here's my problem. I've tried [video example](http://ashbb.github.io/green_shoes/Video.html) from greenshoes samples. But I can't run it because of this:

`require': cannot load such file -- win32api (LoadError)`

So this gives me a message that I have to install win32api gem. I've tried to install **win32api** with this:

`gem install win32-api`

But it gives me this message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

ERROR:  Error installing win32-api:
     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

checking for strncpy_s()... no
creating Makefile

```
make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling win32/api.c
win32/api.c:2:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [api.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8 for inspection.
```

Results logged to /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/win32-api-1.4.8/gem_make.out

Here's my ruby version

`ruby 2.1.2.p95`

Here's the part of backtrace:

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/README

Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8
Exception`NoMethodError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:71 - undefined method `seek' for #

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api.rb

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api.rb

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api.rb

Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader/entry.rb:126 - undefined method`readpartial' for #

Exception `NoMethodError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:71 - undefined method`seek' for #

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api_callback.rb

vm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api_callback.rb

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api_callback.rb

Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test
Exception`NoMethodError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:71 - undefined method `seek' for #

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api_function.rb

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api_function.rb

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test/test_win32_api_function.rb

Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/test
Exception`NoMethodError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:71 - undefined method `seek' for #

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/win32-api.gemspec

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/win32-api.gemspec

Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/win32-api.gemspec

Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/win32-api-1.4.8
Exception`NoMethodError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:71 - undefined method `seek' for #

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/win32-api-1.4.8/gem.build_complete

Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/win32-api-1.4.8

Exception `Gem::InstallError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89 - make failed, exit code 2
Exception`Gem::InstallError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:53 - make failed, exit code 2
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/msdc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/win32-api-1.4.8

Exception `Gem::Ext::BuildError' at /home/msdc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:143 - ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Did you succeed in installing gstreamer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158867/trouble-with-installation-of-gstreamer-gem-in-linux-mint  ? If so, what did you do? This error seems to be closely related to gstreamer.  I can't get this running either (in Fedora Linux, but my error is `LoadError: cannot load such file -- gst`) so I don't think I will be able to help you any further.

Comment: It is not an answer, but you could experiment with why's Shoes: http://shoesrb.com/  In contrast with green_shoes, Shoes::Video relies on different video libraries: videolan and ffmpeg , which tend to be well supported in Linux and might bring you more luck. http://shoesrb.com/manual/Video.html

Comment: Please post the stack trace that was printed with the LoadError. This may help someone to track down which ruby file is trying to use win32_api and why.

Comment: I've already fixed my gstreamer problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158867/trouble-with-installation-of-gstreamer-gem-in-linux-mint

Comment: (I guess ordinary green_shoes programs work for you, but I'll ask just in case.)

Comment: It seems that `win32-api` gem is required by line 105 of `lib\plugins\video.rb` (if that helps anyone.)

Answer (score 0):

The message `fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory` means that your C compiler cannot find your Windows SDK, and in particular the windows.h header file.

If you have that header file, you need to fix your C compiler's configuration.

If not, you need to obtain the Windows SDK.

This might help:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx

windows.h is in several places in Debian-derived GNU/Linux distributions. One such place is the `mingw-w64-i686-dev` package, but I don't know which package, if any, you need to run green_shoes video.

Comment: Here's trouble. I'm using Linux Mint, so how can I install it?

Comment: It seems to be an open issue in Github : https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes/issues/76